# On a full article page should the article title be inside the <article> tag?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

If I put the article title (which is also the main title of the page) outside the `<article>` tag, the document outline has the main title of the page being the article title. Which seems desirable.

i.e.

```
<h1>My wonderful article</h1> 
<article>   
     <p>Text of my article</p> 
</article>
```

However the `<article>` tag specification says

> The article element represents a section of content that forms an
>   independent part of a document or site;

My interpretation of that is to be an "independent part" it needs the article title in it. The title is definitely a dependent part of the article.

However, if you put the article title in the `<article>` tag, the page is untitled in a document outline.

What is best practice here?

Comment: Why not use one title for the page and other title for the article ? Also if the main content of the page contains only single article, then `article` element is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

When the document only contains this article, then omit the `article` element:

```html
<body>
  <h1>My wonderful article</h1>
  <p>…</p>
</body>
```

When the document contains also other things (like a site-wide navigation, a sidebar with related articles etc.), then **you don’t want the article’s heading to be the document’s heading**:

```html
<!-- wrong! -->
<body> 
  <h1>My wonderful article</h1>
  <article></article>
  <nav></nav>
</body>
```

Why? Because the site-wide navigation should not be in scope of a heading which is only about the article. The document heading should describe the *whole* content of the document, not only its main part. So you need such an additional document heading.

Either provide a document heading explicitly (typically¹, the site name is used) …

```
<body> 
  <h1>My wonderful site</h1>
  <article><h1>My wonderful article</h1></article>
  <nav></nav>
</body>
```

… or omit it (… if you must; which requires you to use sectioning elements wherever appropriate), essentially creating an unlabeled entry in the outline:

```
<body> 
  <article><h1>My wonderful article</h1></article>
  <nav></nav>
</body>
```

(¹ Some of my related answers with more details: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915502/1591669), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920215/1591669), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40262/16414).)

Comment: Semantically I tend to agree. But then displaying this I think it is valid for the primary title on the page to be that of the article, not another title for the site. Which seems contradictory to this.

Comment: @DanSingerman: *Visually* you mean? Sure, you can give more graphical weight to the article heading; you could even visually hide the document/site title (which would be unusual, as the site name/logo is typically shown all the time, right?).

Comment: If you show a logo but not some text for the site name, then that is going to be no good for a document outline. If you hide the title that is bad for SEO (I think google see it is possibly black hat)

Comment: @DanSingerman: The document outline does not have to consist of text elements only. In case of an `img`, the `alt` content will be used by user-agents not supporting images (`<h1><img src="" alt="…" /></h1>`). --- Visually hiding headings is not per se bad; it’s a common practice for structural headings (for example "Navigation"). It depends on *why* you want to hide *which* heading. But I guess that’s beside the point (discussing SEO is off-topic here), as that was only an example about how the styling doesn’t influence the document outline.